# Who creates the Session Identifier in http response?

Tags: http

Who creates the Session Identifier in http response?

im confused about this. does Web-server generates session identifier in first response ? or web-application creates session identifier?

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol, so the web server doesn't do anything involving sessions.

Comment: well it was stateless until they invented the cookies, which in fact introduce a state (managed by the browser, and eventually by the application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web application (or the framework the application uses) is in charge for that. Not the HTTP server.